# Centering some items within div

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of a problem with centering parts of my navigation. Here's the markup structure:

```
<div id="pagination_navigation">
    <a href="#" class="first">First</a>
    <a href="#" class="page_item">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="page_item active_item">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="last">Last</a>
</div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
#pagination_navigation {
    text-align: center;
}
#pagination_navigation .first {
    float: left;
}
#pagination_navigation .last {
    float:right;
}
#pagination_navigation .page_item {
    display: inline;
    width: 6px;
    height: 10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: url(fancyimage.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Basically I want all the page_items to be centered with a small margin between each other, and the first and last links should be on their respective sides. At first I was going to wrap all the page_items in a div and center that using margin: 0 auto; but the markup structure can't change, because the Javascript expects this exact structure.

With the CSS you see above, the page_items are centered as they should, but text-indent: -9999px; doesn't work, so the text is still there (which I do not want). Any idea on how I can get rid of the text but keep the link and the centering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a dot before  `page_item` in your CSS.

This means that the CSS targetting `#pagination_navigation page_item` has no effect on any elements.

What you want is:

```
#pagination_navigation .page_item {
    display: inline;
    width: 6px;
    height: 10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: url(fancyimage.png) no-repeat;
}
```

The dot before `page_item` indicates that you're refering to a class name. Without the dot you're refering to an element with the name `page_item`.

Also, you can't use the `text-indent` on inline level elements. Changing this to `inline-block` will fix your problem.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wBreU/1/

Comment: The missing dot was simply a typo when I wrote my post. In the actual code, the dot is there. Changing to inline-block seems to have done the trick though!

Comment: Ah nice. I was just sugesting that and I posted a quick demo too.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
#pagination_navigation page_item {
```

To this:

```
#pagination_navigation .page_item {
```

And things should start working better!

You could also use "display: **inline-block**;" instead of "display: **inline**".  It should be what you need.

Comment: There's also the problem of his links being inline levelso the text-indent wont work as he wants. And really, the same answer 4 minutes after mine? :-)

Comment: @Jamie: I didn't see your answer when I started typing.  But I noticed that you pulled my "inline-block" suggestion into your answer! :)

Comment: haha touche. I didn't see your inline-block answer until after I'd updated :-) Ah well, +1 for being a good sport :)